# xrandr lists audio (over HDMI) but aplay doesn't

Tags: 14.04, sound, hdmi, intel, xrandr

I'm on 14.04 and trying to get sound over displayport -> HDMI -> TV on my Dell Optiplex 780 with Intel GMA4500 graphics. The issue is not (yet) displayport -> HDMI which seems to be adapter dependent but at this moment, aplay -l does not list the Intel card at all.

`xrandr --verbose` lists the TV, EDID and

```
audio: auto 
supported: force-dvi off auto on
```

I was hopeing that if the graphics didn't support sound in the first place, `xrandr` wouldn't list audio either and that this is just a driver issue.

I have tried installing the official Intel driver (with the graphical installer), added `i915.disable_power_well=0`, updated to alsa-daily and upgraded to the latest kernel as per suggestions from the internet itself. No change.

Graphics is fine though.

Any ideas?

```
$ lsmod | grep snd

snd_hda_codec_analog    15144  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    68898  1 snd_hda_codec_analog
snd_hda_intel          30779  1 
snd_hda_controller     31921  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         139816  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_hda_codec_analog
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_page_alloc         18710  3 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69322  13 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_analog,snd_seq_midi
soundcore              12680  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
```

```
$ aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD1984A Analog [AD1984A Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 2: AD1984A Alt Analog [AD1984A Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
$ xrandr --verbose
```

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  23161
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (0x47) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  23161
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff001e6d010001010101
        01150103801009780aee91a3544c9926
        0f5054a10800714f8180010101010101
        010101010101023a801871382d40582c
        4500a05a0000001e1b2150a051001e30
        48883500a05a0000001c000000fd003a
        3e1e5310000a202020202020000000fc
        004c472054560a2020202020202001e2
        020337f14e101f841305140302122021
        2215012615075009570778030c002000
        b82d20c00e01400a3c08101810981058
        103810e3050301011d8018711c162058
        2c2500a05a0000009e011d007251d01e
        206e285500a05a0000001e023a801871
        382d40582c4500a05a0000001e000000
        00000000000000000000000000000021
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
  1920x1080 (0x47)  148.5MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x8e)  148.5MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock   56.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   50.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x8f)  148.4MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.4KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   59.9Hz
  1920x1080i (0x90)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   33.8KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock   60.1Hz
  1920x1080i (0x91)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock   28.1KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock   50.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x92)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   33.8KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   30.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x93)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock   28.1KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   25.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x94)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock   27.0KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   24.0Hz
  1920x1080i (0x95)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   33.7KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x96)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   33.7KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   30.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0x97)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock   27.0KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   24.0Hz
  1280x1024 (0x98)  108.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock   64.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   60.0Hz
  1360x768 (0x99)   84.8MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock   47.7KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  776 total  798           clock   59.8Hz
  1152x864 (0x9a)  108.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock   75.0Hz
  1280x720 (0x9b)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock   45.0KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x720 (0x9c)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock   37.5KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock   50.0Hz
  1280x720 (0x9d)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock   45.0KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock   59.9Hz
  1440x576i (0x9e)   27.0MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
        h: width  1440 start 1464 end 1590 total 1728 skew    0 clock   15.6KHz
        v: height  576 start  580 end  586 total  625           clock   50.1Hz
  1024x768 (0x9f)   65.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0xa0)   40.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  720x576 (0xa1)   27.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock   31.2KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock   50.0Hz
  720x480 (0xa2)   27.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock   60.0Hz
  720x480 (0xa3)   27.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
  640x480 (0xa4)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   60.0Hz
  640x480 (0xa5)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
  720x400 (0xa6)   28.3MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock   70.1Hz
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  23161
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x45
    Timestamp:  23161
    Subpixel:   no subpixels
    Clones:
    CRTCs:      2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter:

Comment: What's your aplay output? You could update your question by [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/581919/edit) it

Comment: Did you go to system settings - sound and select the HDMI port?

Comment: No. When aplay -l didn't list it, I didn't expect the graphical interface would say anything else. Are they different? Both are not part of ALSA?